# Фильтрация на сайте JS без jquery

Tags: javascript, фильтрация

Задача: есть несколько h3, при вводе в input букв - начать выводить подходящие h3.
html-разметка

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()" id="myInput" placeholder="Search for names">
<div class="subject" id="subject">
    <h3>Физика</h3>
    <h3>Алгебра</h3>
    <h3>Геометрия</h3>
    <h3>Биология</h3>
</div>
```

js:

```
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, h3, i;
    input = document.getElementById('myInput');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    h3 = document.getElementsByTagName('h3');

    for (i=0; i<h3.length; i++){
        h3 = h3[i].getElementsByTagName("h3")[0];
        if (document.innerHTML.toUpperCase() .indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            h3[i].style.display = "";
        }
        else {
            h3[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Можете подсказать, где я допускаю ошибку?

Comment: `h3 = h3[i].getElementsByTagName("h3")[0]` вот здесь у вас ошибка. В переменной `h3` уже содержатся все элементы `h3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле у вас было много ошибок.

```
function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, h3, i;
    input = document.getElementById('myInput');
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    h3 = document.getElementsByTagName('h3'); // Здесь в переменной h3 уже содержаться все элементы.

    for (i=0; i<h3.length; i++){
        h3 = h3[i].getElementsByTagName("h3")[0]; // Соответственно здесь не надо вызывать getElementsByTagName (1). К тому же, не надо переопределять h3 переменную, лучше создать новую (2)
        if (document.innerHTML.toUpperCase() .indexOf(filter) > -1) { // здесь не надо смотреть содержимое всего документа, надо смотреть h3(3)
            h3[i].style.display = ""; // здесь в  h3 уже содержится один нужный элемент h3 (4)
        }
        else {
            h3[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Посмотрите пример:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, h3s, i;
  input = document.getElementById('myInput');
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  h3s = document.getElementsByTagName('h3');

  for (i = 0; i < h3s.length; i++) {
    let h3 = h3s[i];
    if (h3.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      h3.style.display = "";
    } else {
      h3.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction()" id="myInput" placeholder="Search for names">
<div class="subject" id="subject">
  <h3>Физика</h3>
  <h3>Алгебра</h3>
  <h3>Геометрия</h3>
  <h3>Биология</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: какие ошибки-то?

Comment: @Grundy их было 4 штуки. Думаете, стоит расписать каждую? У ТС не получится сравнить мой код со своим и найти различия?

Comment: большое спасибо за ответы.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko хорошо реализовали.+

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, конечно стоит расписать каждую. На первый взгляд - код один и тот же

Comment: @Grundy не уверен, что стало лучше)

Comment: а где обещанные 4 ошибки?:)

Comment: @Grundy наслаждайтесь, я их пронумеровал))

Comment: 1 и 2 по сути одна ошибка, если ее убрать(всю строчку) останется только ошибка с документом - итого 2 ошибки:)

Comment: @Grundy мы не ищем легких путей!